# Density function of waiting time

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-function, density-function, exponential-distribution

```
    ◮ A post office has two clerks.
    ◮ Service time for each clerk is 
      exponentially distributed by parameters λ1 , λ2. 
    ◮ When you arrive, 
     both clerks are busy but no one else waiting.
    You will enter service when either clerk becomes free.
    ◮ Calculate the density function
 of the time the customer will have to wait until his turn.
```

The answer is:

[image]

Can someone explain me why?
I also have the full explanation of the answer but I can't really understand it.
They set 2 expansional variables that indicate about the time of each clerk (T1 and T2), and found the minimum between them and few more things and got to the answer.

I did read about density functions and did see here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution

that the PDF is : ${λe}^{λx}$
and
[image]

but I can't figure it out, how should I use it it order to solve the question.
Should I take it as granted? that every PDF is in that form, without the need to prove anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is very easy: the time you have to wait before being served is the mininum between the two waiting times.

The only problem is to understand which is the CDF of the minimum: here is an easy proof

Set $Z=min(X,Y)$

$$P(Z>z)=P(X>z;Y>z)=P(X>z)P(Y>z)=e^{-\lambda_1 z}e^{-\lambda_2 z}=e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)z}$$

Thus the CDF of Z is

$$F_Z(z)=P(Z\leq z)=1-e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)z}$$

take the derivative of F to get the desired density finding (setting $\lambda=\lambda_1+\lambda_2$) exactly the solution you posted.

$$f_Z(z)=\frac{d}{dz}=(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)z}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0;+\infty)}(z)$$

Comment: why do I need the CDF of Z? Can't I just get the desired density finding based only on the P(Z) that you have found? Because we don't use the "1 minus P(Z)" anywhere in the answer.

Comment: @BenTyler : $1-P(Z)$ is enough...but the text asked explicitly to find $Z$ density...that is the derivative of $F_Z(z)$. I would like to encourage you to click the check mark if this answer was helpful for you. It'll encourage others to answer your questions in the future

Comment: i'm confused. Why the $1-P(Z)$ is enough? I'm looking for the pdf not the cdf, correct me if i'm wrong. Why am I able to set $\lambda=\lambda_1+\lambda_2$ ? I'm confused about this whole PDF,CDF topic.. I mean yes. In Wikipedia, they write that every pdf is ${\lambda e}^{\lambda x}$, but I still can't figure it out how to use it in that answer.

Comment: @BenTyler the CDF is enough to solve any problem because with it you can calculate any probability you are requested to do. The pdf, that is the derivative of F is explicilty requested in your exercise. I added also the result of the derivative....I hope now it is clear